# How do I capture only those columns in multiple rows in which user has changed values?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Are there are any approaches in ASP.NET or JavaScript where i run update stored procedure on only those rows in which specific columns have been updated by user?

For example: if there are multiple rows

```
row1= [column1 column2 column3 column4 coumn 5]
row2= [column1 column2 column3 column4 coumn 5]
row3= [column1 column2 column3 column4 coumn 5]
row4= [column1 column2 column3 column4 coumn 5]
```

If the column 2 and Column 3 are updated in row 1 and column 1 and column 4 are update in row 3 i want to capture only these rows and columns and pass it as JSON string to List which I am then converting to DataTable?

What approach should I take ?

What I have tried:

Googled some samples but an expert opinion is always best

Answer (score 1):

There is a **very convoluted** way to achieve this. If anyone knows of a cleaner way, *please* post it.

You need to do the following:

Add to your Model:
- a Boolean property (column) that will be hidden and used as a change Identifier

Set up your table in your view like this (my example is in Razor):

```
@{
int j = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < Model.itemList.Count; i++)
{
     <tr>
          <td>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].columnOne, new { onkeypress = "markAsChanged(" + @j + ", " + @i + ")" })
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].columnTwo, new { onkeypress = "markAsChanged(" + @j + ", " + @i + ")" })
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].columnThree, new { onkeypress = "markAsChanged(" + @j + ", " + @i + ")" })
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].columnFour, new { onkeypress = "markAsChanged(" + @j + ", " + @i + ")" })
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].columnFive, new { onkeypress = "markAsChanged(" + @j + ", " + @i + ")" })
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.itemList[i].IsChanged)
          </td>
     </tr>
     j++;
}
```

Your JavaScript function will edit the hidden element as soon as someone changes a field for a row:

```
function rerunOldChange(rowIndex, changeIndex) {
    var table = document.getElementById("changeTable");
    var j = rowIndex;
    var i = changeIndex;

    var currentRow = table.rows[j];
    var cellSix = currentRow.cells[5];

    var thisRowIsChanged = "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'itemList_" + i + "__IsChanged' name = 'itemList[" + i + "].IsChanged' value = 'true' />"

    cellSix.innerHTML = thisRowIsChanged;
}
```

What it is doing is changing the value of the boolean as soon as someone presses a key on that field. So when you pass the list to your controller in order to post, you can do so only for rows that have a boolean value of True.

Answer (score 1):

I'll tack on some updates and simplification to @C Murphy's response, but setting a hidden field in your viewmodel is the best option. I would recommend using a checkbox, as it is boolean by default and easy to manipulate with its `checked` attribute.

The [keypress event is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), and doesn't fire on all keys - in particular, the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys do not trigger it, so someone could delete everything in a field and no update would occur. Instead, use the `keydown` event; this has sort of the *opposite* effect, as every key triggers it, including <kbd>Shift</kbd> and other keys that may not actually change the field. You can validate changes in other code if you want to.

I removed the code checking for changes per column, because I assume your update logic asks for all the object's data, or with EF probably expects an entire object to be passed.

Razor:

```cs
// A text field, change PropertyName and add where needed in markup
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].PropertyName, new { onkeydown = "markAsChanged(" + i + ")" })

// Hidden checkbox for the IsChanged property
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.itemList[i].PropertyName, new { hidden = "" })
```

The Javascript:

```js
// Modern browsers
var markAsChanged = function(i) {
    document.GetElementById('itemList_' + i + '__IsChanged').checked = true;
};

// Use for legacy support with jQuery
var markAsChanged = function(i) {
    $('#itemList_' + i + '__IsChanged').checked = true;
};
```

If you wanted to clean up your view and leave out the event handlers, you could add them with some more Javascript.