# How to only bind new inputs data instead of all the data of form using the ajax call to send data to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have almost 150 rows in my datatatble and there is an input field value which user can change in any row and then press the bulk update to submit the form currently I am using serializeArray() function to send all the 150 rows no matter new value is inserted or not by user which cause too much delay in postback is there a way that I only bind changed values from form, not all 150 rows.

```
<form id="share">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().Id)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagName)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagCategory)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagValue)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center"> Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.tags.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagCategory)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model.tags[i].Id, @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="bulkupdate">BulkUpdate</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#share').on('submit', function (e) {
                debugger;
                // Prevent actual form submission
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = table.$('input').serializeArray();
                // Submit form data via Ajax
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdate", "Home")',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell what framework you are using. I see some annotations, but I can't recognise them. Also, users specified in that framework/language will find your question better if you tag your question with it.

Comment: Axel Kholer i am using MVC Asp.net

Comment: add a hidden input field with value = 0 for each row with unique identity by some logic.  for each row update change the value to 1 for that hidden filed. You can check for the changes in that hidden field before sending the serialised content to controller.

Comment: I recently answered [another similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382476/12309486).